# Why is this passing a string and not an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I am not understanding something, I have a model in rails that has two ways of assigning tags to a post, one is through an array, the other is singular.

```
  def tag_names=(names)
    self.tags = names.map{ |name| Tag.where(name: name).first_or_create }
  end

  def tag_name=(tag_name)
    single_tag = [tag_name]
    tag_names = single_tag
  end
```

If on this post model you call: `@post.tag_name = ['asdsad', '12312312']` You get two tags assigned to the post

If you do: `@post.tag_name = '23423423'` you get nothing, and the tests are failing, the reason for this is, if you put a `puts names` in the top method, what comes through is not an array but a string, even though I am doing:

```
    single_tag = [tag_name]
    tag_names = single_tag
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
  def tag_name=(tag_name)
    single_tag = [tag_name]
    tag_names = single_tag
  end
```

To

```
 def tag_name=(tag_name)
    single_tag = [tag_name]
    self.tag_names = single_tag  ## Note self.tag_names
  end
```

Currently `tag_names` is being treated as a local variable so your method `tag_name=` is not getting called. You need to specify an explicit receiver for the setter method. `self.tag_names = single_tag` would call the `tag_name=` method.